# How to add data icons in listview item template

Tags: listview, kendo-ui, listviewitem

I am using the JQuery initialization syntax.

As of now, I create my desired listview links like this:

```
<li data-icon="featured"><a>My Listview Item Link</a></li>
```

This gives me a listview link with the "featured" font icon on the left, followed by the link text, followed by a small arrow on the right.

What I am trying to do is convert to using templates, but I'm having trouble achieving the same result as describe above. Here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="mListviewTemplate">
    <a data-role="listview-link">${name}</a>
</script>
```

This results in what I need, except for the missing font icon. The documentation states I can add an `<img>` element to get a font icon, but it's a bit vague and with no example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just choose an element and add the `.km-icon` and `.km-featured` css classes to it.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="mListviewTemplate">
    <span class="km-icon km-featured"></span><a data-role="listview-link">${name}</a>
</script>
```

You can inspect the icons at [kendo's mobile demo page](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/listview/index.html) and see that this is exactly how it is rendered.

Comment: Yeah I did inspect their mobile demo page, but how would one use the img element, as stated in their documentation under Item Icons: [ListView Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/listview) ?

Comment: The Kendo UI Mobile font icons can't be used with an IMG tag.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking as well. No worries, I'll mark this as the answer and send Kendo a message to maybe update this line in their documentation - "An icon can be set in two ways - either by adding an img element inside the li element, or by setting an icon data attribute to the li element."